# apply sort arrows to the second row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, datatables

I am using jquery data tables.

i want to have the sort arrows applied to the second row of the table not the first.

HTML:

```
<table id="tableUsers" class="datatable">
            <thead>                                                       
                <tr class="filterRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td data-rownum="2">
                        @Html.Partial("_FilterDropDown", Model.RoleList)
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td data-rownum="8">
                        @Html.Partial("_FilterDropDown", Model.EnabledList)
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <th class="width-110">User name
                    </th>
                    <th class="width-110">Name
                    </th>
                    <th class="width-110">Role
                    </th>
                    <th class="width-200">Email
                    </th>
                    <th class="width-90">Created
                    </th>
                    <th>DateSort
                    </th>
                    <th class="width-80">Enabled
                    </th>
                    <th class="width-90">Action
                    </th>
                    <th>EnabledSort
                    </th>
                </tr>    
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I want the arrows on the second row. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// copy the filter row
var filterRow = $("#tableUsers .filterRow").clone();
// remove the filter row
$("#tableUsers .filterRow").remove();
// initialize the data table
$("#tableUsers").dataTable();
// re-add the filter row
$("#tableUsers thead tr:first").before(filterRow);
```

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick some formatting issues but i will work them out. Thanks!

Comment: @Beginner - It appears the DataTable plugin can handle your desire natively you just have to use the proper classes and/or role attributes https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html  inspect the html of the example table it has 2 header rows but only puts the sorting elements on the 2nd row.